# Orthogonality of a 2nd Rank Tensor and its Dual in Lorentz Space

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus

I am trying to show the orthogonality of the 2nd rank anti-symmetric tensor $A^{ik}$ and its dual $A^{*ik}.$    Using a text's definition of the dual as  $e^{iklm}*A_{lm}/2$, I have tried to pair elements of the product.  For example, I start with  $A^{01}*e^{0123}*A_{23}$ and list the non-zero permutations of the indices, of which there are six tensor elements, $A^{01}, A^{02}, A^{03}, A^{12}, A^{13}, A^{23}$ and those with sub-scripts, multiplied by the Levi-Civita tensor elements of the 4th rank, to form non zero terms for addition. They look like  $A*e*A/2$. Of these, the element with superior 01 can only be multiplied by the element 23, 02 only with 13, 03 only with 12, each pair permuted and each pair exchanged.  I listed all 24 terms and tried to pair positive products with negative ones using the anti-symmetry of the $As$ and that of the Levi-Civita tensor but could not. Where am I in error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My tabulation does yield the zero total expected.  One may realize the pairing of positive and negative values by taking into account the effects of raising and lowering indices.  Since the 0 index may appear only once because of Levi-Civita, when both A tensors undergo their indices changed in elevation, only one of the tensors has its sign changed.  The pairing is as follows:   $$A^{ik}*e^{iklm}*A_{lm} = -A^{lm}*e^{lmik}*A_{ik}.$$